# operator= between two std::chrono::time_point cause error

Tags: c++, c++-chrono

I have a struct which contain a `std::chrono::system_clock::time_point`

```
struct NetInfo {
    std::chrono::system_clock::time_point time;
    std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point start;
};
```

And when I try to assign one of the time_point to the result of `std::chrono::system_clock::now()`

```
    api::NetInfo ni;
    ni.start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
```

I get this huge error

```
    /home/rootkid/rendu/cpp2/cpp_zia/lib/NetService/src/NetService.cpp:48:51: error: no match for ‘operator=’ (operand types are ‘std::chrono::_V2::steady_clock::time_point {aka std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::_V2::steady_clock, std::chrono::duration<long int, std::ratio<1, 1000000000> > >}’ and ‘std::chrono::_V2::system_clock::time_point {aka std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::_V2::system_clock, std::chrono::duration<long int, std::ratio<1, 1000000000> > >}’)
         ni.start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
                                                   ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/7.2.1/thread:38:0,
                 from /home/rootkid/rendu/cpp2/cpp_zia/lib/NetService/./include/NetService.h:3,
                 from /home/rootkid/rendu/cpp2/cpp_zia/lib/NetService/src/NetService.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/7.2.1/chrono:610:14: note: candidate: constexpr std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::_V2::steady_clock, std::chrono::duration<long int, std::ratio<1, 1000000000> > >& std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::_V2::steady_clock, std::chrono::duration<long int, std::ratio<1, 1000000000> > >::operator=(const std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::_V2::steady_clock, std::chrono::duration<long int, std::ratio<1, 1000000000> > >&)
       struct time_point
              ^~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/7.2.1/chrono:610:14: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘std::chrono::_V2::system_clock::time_point {aka std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::_V2::system_clock, std::chrono::duration<long int, std::ratio<1, 1000000000> > >}’ to ‘const std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::_V2::steady_clock, std::chrono::duration<long int, std::ratio<1, 1000000000> > >&’
/usr/include/c++/7.2.1/chrono:610:14: note: candidate: constexpr std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::_V2::steady_clock, std::chrono::duration<long int, std::ratio<1, 1000000000> > >& std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::_V2::steady_clock, std::chrono::duration<long int, std::ratio<1, 1000000000> > >::operator=(std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::_V2::steady_clock, std::chrono::duration<long int, std::ratio<1, 1000000000> > >&&)
/usr/include/c++/7.2.1/chrono:610:14: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘std::chrono::_V2::system_clock::time_point {aka std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::_V2::system_clock, std::chrono::duration<long int, std::ratio<1, 1000000000> > >}’ to ‘std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::_V2::steady_clock, std::chrono::duration<long int, std::ratio<1, 1000000000> > >&&’
```

Any Idea of what am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: `start` is a `steady_clock`'s time point and you try to assign from a `system_clock` time point, you cannot do that. Both time point types are different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Though not specified, it is a de-facto standard that `system_clock` is measuring [Unix Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) (approximately time duration since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC), though with differing precisions on each platform.

The epoch of `steady_clock` is also unspecified, and no de-facto standard has evolved.  Different platforms do different things.  For example on my platform `steady_clock` measures the time since the computer booted up.

`<chrono>` was designed to catch as many logic errors as possible *at compile-time*.  It would be a logic error to assign a `system_clock::time_point` to a `steady_clock::time_point` since these two clocks are measuring against different epochs.

A future standard *might* offer a way to "transform" or "cast" one clock's `time_point` to another, but it won't be a straightforward assignment.  It would have to involve some computation which takes into account the difference in the epochs.  Otherwise the `time_point` would represent a different instant in time after the assignment compared to before the assignment.

**tl;dr:** The compiler has caught a logic error for you at compile-time.